# Having issues changing .word to .equ

Tags: assembly, arm, microcontroller, directive, nxp-microcontroller

I'm having this lab class about microcontrollers (we're using FRDM-KL25Z128) and I'm having trouble with the directives .word and .equ.

First, the sample code our professor gave us is meant to blink the red LED on the FRDM board, and it's the following: http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/cursos/EA871/2s2016/UW/codes/exp2.s

We have some questions to answer before modifying the code to make it blink the three LED's at the same time and make a white light, but that's not the problem here.

In the bottom of the code, all of the registers addresses are being defined with .word directive (since we're using 32 bits words). One of the questions is to answer if we can substitute the directive .word to .equ.

My first though was that yes, I can substitute .word for .equ because the last directive is assigning a constant value to a label, and since I do not want to change the values of those labels, .equ should be fine to use.

But when I tested it, by commenting those lines:

```
SIM_SCGC5: @ Endereço do SIM_SCGC5
.word 0x40048038
```

And writing:

```
.equ SIM_SCGC5, 0x40048038
```

Which should assign the value 0x40048038 to the SIM_SCGC5 label. But the code won't work, I'll get an error on the following line:

```
ldr     r3,SIM_SCGC5
```

Saying:

> invalid offset, value too big

So I'm not sure if I either screwed up in the .equ directive or if, by default, .equ assigns a value that occupies more bits than LDR can handle.

What can be the problem here?

Some notes:

- I'm starting to code in Assembly together with a microcontroller, so I'm still missing a lot of info, like the hardware limitations. So I could just have written a bunch of random words without knowing.
- Sorry for the long preparation. I know that long posts aren't the favorites of Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange in general), but I didn't want to throw a question without a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.word` assembles 4 bytes into the output file at the current position.  If you want the data stored there, you have to load it from the address where you put it.  If you put a label in front of it, the symbol's value is the address.

`.equ` defines an assemble-time constant, for use as a value in future expressions.  The symbol's value is the constant, **there is no address**, and no bytes in the object file.  So you can use something defined with `.equ` as an immediate operand for other instructions, like `add`.  You can't use it with loads/stores.

---

Putting an immediate constant into a register is different from loading from a fixed address.  [Use `ldr r3, =SIM_SCGC5` to have the assembler generate whatever sequence of instructions](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731147386.htm) it decides is best to generate that constant in r3.  They confusingly chose the same mnemonic for this pseudo-op as for an actual load instruction.

See also [Why use LDR over MOV (or vice versa) in ARM assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046686/why-use-ldr-over-mov-or-vice-versa-in-arm-assembly).  This is probably a duplicate of an existing SO question, but I haven't found an ideal dup target yet.

When `SIM_SCGC5` is defined with a `.equ` the instruction `ldr r3, SIM_SCGC5` would I think try to load from that absolute address.  The error you get is because there's no way to encode that as a single instruction.

It will use [`mov` or `movn` with a shifted/rotated immediate if possible](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/immediates.html), otherwise falling back to a PC-relative load from a nearby constant pool.  I think two instructions to set the low 16 bits and the high 16 bits might also be possible.

See also [Constants on ARM](https://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2010/07/27/how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture), and various SO questions like [Arm cortex-m3 mov and ldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624823/arm-cortex-m3-mov-and-ldr).

Answer (score 4):

.word as used here

```
ldr r0,hello
nop
nop
nop
hello: .word 0x12345678
```

is similar to

```
unsigned int word = 0x12345678
```

hello: is a label .word has nothing to do with it.  Just means I want to use a label for an address at this point, can put code there or data or whatever.  Like unsigned int in C you are allocating some space in the program.

.equ though is like a define you are not allocating space, you are simply defining some replacement for that string.

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o
...
00000000 <hello-0x10>:
   0:   e59f0008    ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; 10 <hello>
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
00000010 <hello>:
  10:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

If I add this

```
.equ JELLO, 0x22
ldr r0,hello
nop
nop
nop
hello: .word 0x12345678
```

No change, if I do this

```
.equ JELLO, 0x12345678
ldr r0,JELLO
```

.equ is a define like substitution.

```
ldr r0,0x12345678

so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:2: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up
```

now if we want the VALUE in r0, then it is a syntax problem.

```
mov r0,#0x12345678
```

Which we cant do in ARM, the instructions are either 16 or 32 bits and thats it, so you cant have a 32 bit immediate AND the opcode AND the registers, etc in 32 bits.  So something has to give, the immediates depending on the instruction set and variations are between a few and up to maybe 11 or 13 bits, normal arm mov instruction full sized arm instructions like 9 significant bits.

```
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:3: Error: invalid constant (12345678) after fixup
```

Interestingly the trick is to go back to load and ask the assembler, I would like the address of the label rather than the thing at the label.

```
ldr r0,=hello
nop
nop
nop
hello: .word 0x12345678
.word 0,1,2,3
```

The assembler has allocated a word for us where it could find a space

```
00000000 <hello-0x10>:
   0:   e59f001c    ldr r0, [pc, #28]   ; 24 <hello+0x14>
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
00000010 <hello>:
  10:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
  14:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
  18:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
  1c:   00000002    andeq   r0, r0, r2
  20:   00000003    andeq   r0, r0, r3
  24:   00000010    andeq   r0, r0, r0, lsl r0
```

Notice it is not loading the thing at address 0x10 into the register, it is loading the thing at address 0x24 the location it added for us, and in that location it is providing the ADDRESS to hello which is 0x10 so r0 will get 0x10 instead of 0x12345678 by adding that equals sign.  Kind of like removing the asterisk on a one dimensional pointer in C you get the address of the pointer not the thing the pointer points to.

So knowing this ldr rx,=something means I want the ADDRESS of that label, what if we were to just put an address there instead of a label that represents an address?

```
ldr r0,=0x87654321
nop
nop
nop
hello: .word 0x12345678
.word 0,1,2,3
```

it just happens to work

```
0000000 <hello-0x10>:
   0:   e59f001c    ldr r0, [pc, #28]   ; 24 <hello+0x14>
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
00000010 <hello>:
  10:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
  14:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
  18:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
  1c:   00000002    andeq   r0, r0, r2
  20:   00000003    andeq   r0, r0, r3
  24:   87654321    strbhi  r4, [r5, -r1, lsr #6]!
```

So this does not justify that you can blindly replace .word with .equ in any gnu assembler based instruction set you want, but due to dumb luck you can almost get there by fixing the syntax

```
.equ JELLO,0x12345678
ldr r0,=JELLO
nop
nop
nop
```

and there you go

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e59f0008    ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; 10 <JELLO-0x12345668>
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  10:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

In general for any/other instruction sets .word to .equ with a load you need to change to a mov

```
.equ JELLO,0x12
ldr r0,hello
mov r0,#JELLO
nop
nop
nop
hello:
.word 0x12


00000000 <hello-0x14>:
   0:   e59f000c    ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; 14 <hello>
   4:   e3a00012    mov r0, #18
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  10:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
00000014 <hello>:
  14:   00000012    andeq   r0, r0, r2, lsl r0
```

using whatever syntax (mov, move, etc.  in x86 mov is used for both load and mov immediate so you would just need to know what if any syntax modification is needed to switch from a label to an immediate (remove some form of word ptr hello syntax perhaps))

Note I was using the legacy gnu assembler syntax above, so using that

```
.equ JELLO,0x12
mov r0,JELLO
```

gives

```
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:4: Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `mov r0,JELLO'
```

But if we use the unified syntax, I guess it doesnt care about the pound sign anymore.

```
.syntax unified
.equ JELLO,0x12
mov r0,JELLO
mov r0,#JELLO

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e3a00012    mov r0, #18
   4:   e3a00012    mov r0, #18
```

Not a fan, supposed to make it easier (well lazier), just makes it worse...which is why I rarely use it unless I have to...YMMV.